# Ways of arranging elements of square matrix

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say I have an NxN matrix, where all of the elements are either 0 or 1.

My question is, how many ways can I arrange the matrix so that in every column, and in every row, there are exactly K 0's and P 1's (with K+P=N)?

(When K=P, the problem is simplified a bit, but I'm interested in generalizing to K not necessarily = P. See this post for the case K=P=N/2: [How many ways are there to fill up a $2n \times 2n$ matrix with $1, -1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289381/how-many-ways-are-there-to-fill-up-a-2n-times-2n-matrix-with-1-1))

Comment: I doubt there's a simple formula for this.

Comment: Gerry is absolutely right. See http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/linalg.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no known explicit formula.

However, the table of values for all combinations of up to $0 < P < N \leq 30$ can be found at ["Counts of semiregular 0-1 matrices"](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/semiregular.html).

The values relevant to this specific question are all those of the form $B(n,p; n,p)$.

For convenience, I have listed some of them below (excluding symmetrical equivalents).

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
N & P & \text{count} \\ \hline
2 & 1 &  2 \\ \hline
3 & 1 & 6 \\ \hline
4 & 1 & 24 \\
4 & 2 & 90 \\ \hline
5 & 1 & 120 \\
5 & 2 & 2040 \\ \hline 
6 & 1 & 720 \\
6 & 2 & 67950 \\
6 & 3 &  297200 \\ \hline
7 & 1 &  5040 \\
7 & 2 & 3110940 \\
7 & 3 & 68938800 \\ \hline
8 & 1 &  40320 \\
8 & 2 &  187530840 \\
8 & 3 &  24046189440 \\
8 & 4 &  116963796250 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$